# how to chose the right frame size for touring bike?

Tags: touring, bike-fit, used-bike

I am going on a two week bike trip with a friend and I can only afford a second hand bike. My concern is that I will wind up buying a bike that I later discover was the wrong size for me.

I know that in an ideal situation I would try out a bunch of bikes at a shop and pick the one that fits the best, but if I am buying one second hand it's going to be more of a, 'ride it around the block and then make a decision' scenario.

Given that, are there some tips / things to keep in mind that would help to lower my chances of buying an ill-fitting bike?

Comment: If a bike shop fits you to a 55 then a 56 may or may not work but you can eliminate a 60 or a 52.  Not really fair to the bike shop to have them fit you with no intent of buying a bike from them but you could get a feel for what a proper fit feels like.

Comment: See this question: [How much does non-ideal frame size matter?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/21495/how-much-does-non-ideal-frame-size-matter/21496#21496) It's not exactly the question you're asking but will give you a good idea of the "tolerances" involved

Comment: For me there are two factors. One is inseam; I want to be able to stand on the ground with both feet while straddling the bike. The other, related to that, is leg extension when pedaling; to use the full leg, I generally want the seat high enough that my leg is not-quite-fully-extended at bottom of stroke (so I can tilt the foot and pull back across the bottom of the cycle if I need to). For my 29" inseam, that seems to mean a 19" or 20" frame to keep the seat post from being set unreasonably high. Your mileage will vary.

Comment: If you're actually buying a touring bike, you could likely get fit on something pretty similar (Trek 520 or something - That thing hasn't changed since the stone age) at your LBS for a modest fee. Then, look for second hand touring bikes with similar sizing.

Comment: Do note that unfortunately there is no single standard for frame size -- two identical frames can have a "size" difference of about 3cm, depending on how measured.  "Standover height", OTOH, is a fairly precise number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How:**

The low tech way:

1. **Measuring tape** Simply take it with you and measure five bikes that are comfy, and five that are not.
2. **Digital camera** Ask someone take a picture of you sitting on the bike, then review the picture to analyse yourself the sitting positions, both those that feel comfortable, and those that feel uncomfortable.

**Geometry:**

1. **Chainstay**. You need long enough chainstay for panniers. My recommendation is 45 cm. Below 42 cm your feet can hit the panniers even with small feet.
2. **Comfort**. You can select the ideal frame size based on different criteria: aerodynamics, efficiency, comfort, resulting speed, etc. For touring, the comfort is 10x more important then speed or anything else. This is because you sit 3-6h a day, for many days. On a tour, you get further by pedaling more and less by pedaling faster. Example: you can be 30-50% faster in an uncomfortable, but speedy position, but you can maintain that only for 1-2h. However, in a comfortable position, you can stay even 6-7h in the saddle.

I'd rather select a slightly smaller bike vs. a slightly bigger bike.

By buying a second hand bike, what you risk is **hidden failures** vs. the gain of lower cost.

- Steel frames: check for "bents" and corrosion
- Alu frames: check for cracks.

Bents usually come from accidents (falling with the bike), and cannot be corrected. You feel it only in the first moments of the riding, after a couple of minutes the feeling can go away. This cannot be repaired. I do have a steel bike that is bent.

Cracks come from big impacts and overload. This can be corrected by welding the alu frame, you need to find an alu-welder. I do have an alu bike with a crack (high quality brand, I didn't take yet the time to find a welder and get it repaired.

For more details, see my response here:
[How do you distinguish a touring bike...](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16373/how-do-you-distinguish-a-touring-bike-from-a-speed-road-bike/23235#23235)